# Is it possible to convert static electricity into current electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current

Generally, static electricity is created by friction between two or more different materials and it doesn't flow through a circuit.

On the other hand, current electricity is the flow of electrons through a circuit.

I want to know if there is any way to convert static electricity into current electricity? If it is indeed possible can we use it to get sufficient energy?

Comment: This is precisely what happens when you shock something after building a static charge, it then moves and becomes a current.

Comment: I am asking about flow through an electric circuit.

Comment: Then touch a grounded circuit after walking over a carpet.

Comment: Well the closest circuit element is a capacitor, technically speaking a capacitor is a storage device for static charges that can then be discharged to power a circuit element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can produce static electricity continuously  for example by a Van de Graaff accelerator (Look it up in wikipedia) it is used to create a current of fast electrons or other elementary particles trough vacuum. One could theoretically use it for current through resistors. But the efficiency would be very, very low, so it has no practical use.

Comment: What other elementary particles?

Comment: Any charged particle or ion , it was used to accelerate protons